# ERWIN create and use database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-modeling

Im trying to generate physical database from my logical model using ERWIN 7.

All is well in the script that is generated automatically, there is only the problem that the model is created in the database "master" which is the default SQL Server, rather than being created in the database that I inserted along with the model.

I cant find a way to associate my MODEL with the database im creating along with the model.

Here is the script that ERWIN auto-generates:

```
> CREATE DATABASE Movies go
>
> 
> 
> 
> ALTER DATABASE Movies SET  RECOVERY FULL go
> 
> 
> 
> CREATE SCHEMA fbd AUTHORIZATION dbo go
> 
> 
> 
> CREATE DEFAULT Default_Value_movies_gen   AS 1 go
> 
> 
> 
> CREATE DEFAULT Default_Value_titulo_movies    AS 'No title' go
```

BUT it should generate automatically:

> CREATE DATABASE Movies go
>
> // Here should be "USE Movies",to use database that ERWIN have just created
>
> ALTER DATABASE Movies SET  RECOVERY FULL go
>
> CREATE SCHEMA fbd AUTHORIZATION dbo go
>
> CREATE DEFAULT Default_Value_movies_gen   AS 1 go
>
> CREATE DEFAULT Default_Value_titulo_movies    AS 'No title' go

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using Erwin 8. I put the target database in `Actions/Database Connection`

Comment: Try to find where Database Connection is. `Tools|Reverse Engineer Option`..

Comment: In my case it is Forward Engineer

Answer (score 1):

You need to make physical model in ERwin and after that you go to Tools->Forward Engineering->
Schema Generation and there you can choose to generate Database.